# Derive explained sum of squared from beta

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, linear-model

May I ask, how should I calculate $$SSE=\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}-\bar{y})^2$$
given
$$\beta=-0.094=\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$
$$intercept=1.9781$$
and 
$\bar{x}=4.9817$,$\bar{y}=1.512, N=100, \sum x^2=2505.8313, \sum xy=750.9786, \sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2=0.9217$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is SSR, and using regression coefficient estimates, we can calculate estimated target values: $\hat y_i = \hat \beta x_i+\hat \beta_0$, then substitute into the formulation of SSR:
$$\begin{align}\text{SSR}&=\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\bar y)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \hat y_i^2 -2 \bar y\sum_{i=1}^n \hat y_i+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \bar y^2}_{\text{known}}\end{align}$$
For the second term, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \hat y_i=\hat\beta\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\hat \beta_0=\hat \beta n\bar x+n\hat \beta_0$$
And, for the third term:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\hat y_i^2=\hat \beta^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+2\hat\beta\hat\beta_0\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\hat\beta_0^2$$
which is composed of all *known* terms.

If you want SSE, just substitute above SSR from SST, which is $\sum (y_i-\bar y)^2$ .